# why boolean variable is passed to useState() is always false? React hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a simple functional component and would like to initialize the state with a boolean, depending on the condition.  For example:

```
export default() => {

  const st = useSelector(state => state.body);
  const { type } = st;

  let bool = type === 'test'

  const [ hidden, setHidden ] = useState(bool) //this is always true

}
```

`st` is just fetching the state from redux, `type` will be condition.  In some cases `type` will be test so `bool` will be true, but when it's initializing the `state` it's always false.

I do a `console.log` after the `useState` and `hidden` displays false???

I'm not sure what's causing to be false.  Am i missing something? I appreciate your help and insights

Comment: `bool` will be set to false unless `type === 'test'`, without knowing what `type` is, this is expected.

Answer (score 7):

As you said

> st is just fetching the state from redux

This is probably the problem.

Probably in the first render, what you get from the redux isn't the correct value (probably `null` or `undefined`), so it sets the default value of the state as `false`, and then happens a second render where it returns the correct value, but won't reassign it to the state.

The default value of `useState` will be set only in the first render, and if in the first render it isn't what you want, it won't change, unless you set it.

What you could do is use `useEffect` hook to reset `hidden` when `type` changes

```
export default () => {

  const st = useSelector(state => state.body);
  const { type } = st;

  let bool = type === 'test';

  const [ hidden, setHidden ] = useState(bool) //this is always true

  // reset hidden if type changes
  useEffect(() => {
      setHidden(type === 'test')
  }, [type])

}
```

Comment: The only thing wrong here is `setHidden` is not needed as a dependency of `useEffect()` as React guarantees it remains unchanged.

Comment: It's not wrong, eslint will give you a warning if you don't pass `setHidden` as dependency. So I added that so people don't complain about eslint. You really don't need it, but it's not wrong to add it.

Comment: Ok, my mistake.

Comment: Actually, my eslint does not complain. See the docs example here, [Tip: Optimizing Performance by Skipping Effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects), the setter is not included in the dependency list.

Comment: @RichardMatsen Your eslint doesn't complain because you probably don't have [eslint-plugin-react-hooks](https://npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) installed. Please take a look at the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#eslint-plugin)

Comment: @RichardMatsen ops, looks like I have and old version of eslint running